# Flask + React GET Request is failing but POST Request is successful

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, fetch

I am a bit of a beginner to React. I developed a Flask backend and now i want to pair it with React for frontend.

I am using `fetch` in React to make the GET Request. When i read the data, the text or the response when i call `response.text()` is the `index.html` file in the `public` directory of my app

Here is my react code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.text()) //Here is the text() i said before
        this.setState({ snippets: response.data })
      })
      .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

Here is the MRE of my flask app:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return {'snippets':['blah','blaha']
```

My proxy in `package.json`

```
    "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
```

My flask backend is running at port 5000 and react at port 3000

One thing to note is that a POST request (from `<form>`) does get proxied to the backend server and i can retrieve the contents of the POST request in flask. Its the GET request using `fetch` that isn't working.

Directory structure:

```
-env
-getcode
  -templates
  -static
  -__init__.py
  -routes.py
-getcode-client
  -src
  -public
run.py
```

Here `getcode` is the directory of the flask app and `getcode-client` contains the React app created using `create-react-app`

NOTE:
Also i tried to setup a manual proxy like this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually

but now the react app is not shown. it completely shows my flask backend's json output.

Package.json:

```
{
    "name": "getcode-client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.3",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe flask is serving some index.html file on `/` route, can you replace `/` with `/api` and try again.

Comment: No templates are being served

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Latest update:**
  Sorry about I misunderstood about proxy in nodejs, and `fetch()` can support this kind of proxy.

After I do some trial and error, you just need to change you path '/' to '/something_else' and the proxy work well.

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return {'snippets':['blah','blaha']}
```

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/test')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.text()) //Here is the text() i said before
        this.setState({ snippets: response.data })
      })
      .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

Wrong information:

This is not issue about python and flask.

<s>You use `fetch()` in javascript, and this is native js function, so it is not related with proxy you set in `package.json`.</s>

If you want to use `fetch()` to get other port, you have to give it the whole url `http://localhost:5000/` or you will get the same port of you react app.

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.text()) //Here is the text() i said before
        this.setState({ snippets: response.data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
```

There are some packages you can use like [fetch-with-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-with-proxy) or [node-https-proxy-agent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-https-proxy-agent), fetch-with-proxy can get HTTP_PROXY env var to set proxy, and you can use the other create proxy agent.

But I recommend that to use other package to send request like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

```
import axios from 'axios';
const axios_ = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
})

class App extends React.Component  {
  componentDidMount() {
    axios_.get('/')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.text()) //Here is the text() i said before
        this.setState({ snippets: response.data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
...}
```

Actually, the proxy you mean is not the proxy we usually talk about, what you want to do is just to point to another port to get the response.

[Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) is about a tunnel or something between your client to server.

Further more, you also can search for reverse proxy that will be the question you want to know too.

Comment: So I know that you have to use nginx in production. Is there a way to use nginx reverse proxy in development. On my local machine??

Comment: After I search for more information, I misunderstanding for proxy in package.json .
I think it is the nodejs proxy problem, it does not support root path '/'.
If you change '/' to '/test' or other else in both fetch and flask route, it work.

Comment: I had tried that using /api in package.json but that also doesn't work

Comment: So in proxy in package.josn would be http;//localhost:5000/test

Comment: Only use http;//localhost:5000

Comment: its still not working. if i change the route to '/home' it gives me 404. the reques goes to port 3000 not 5000

Comment: Can you provider your current code to let me know where the problem is.
Reqs will not go to 5000 port, it will go to 3000 to your react server and then react server go to your flask app, so you got 404 that mean there is not /home path for your flask.
Have you restarted flask server, and check the flask access log get 404 status?

Comment: yea now it works. yes both servers are in debug mode auto reload works

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think that the problem is that your using both React and Flask on localhost, and not specifying the port in the `fetch` requests, try this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/:5000')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.text()) //Here is the text() i said before
        this.setState({ snippets: response.data })
      })
      .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

Or if that doesn't help, maybe change the proxy settings as:

```
"proxy": "127.0.0.1:5000"
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to type out localhost. I want fetch to proxy all the requests to my flask backend.

Comment: What about trying `/:5000`, that should proxy all requests through flask. and I would edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am also relatively new to react. Recently I wrote a flask API and was testing it with a react frontend. There are two things that i did differently to get things working.

1. My `componentDidMount` would look something like this using the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/').then(response => {
    return response.text();
  }).then(response => {
    this.setState({ snippets: response.data })
  }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error)
  });
}
```

2. I use the [flask_cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to prevent `CORS` related issues. Implementation would be something like this

```py
from flask_cors import cross_origin


@cross_origin(origin="*")
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return {'snippets':['blah','blaha']
```

I haven't made any changes to my `package.json` to get the connection between the React frontend and the flask api backend. Hope this helps and good luck with your troubleshooting.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using CRA I would suggest to use their proxy setting.

> To tell the development server to proxy any unknown requests to your API server in development, add a proxy field to your package.json, for example:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
```

In your case this will be on port 5000.

[Here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) is more on the topic.

However, on production I would suggest to use nginx or apache to avoid issues in the future.

@Edit
This is how package.json should look in your case

```
{
"name": "getcode-client",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.3",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
    ]
}  }
```

Comment: It should have, have you tried to restart application & have you put this in correct place in package.json? Could you perhaps past it to your main post? Entire package.json

Comment: The package.json is the normal one that gets created by create with the proxy added. Yes I have restarted the servers and even restarted the computer

Comment: Right, I just wanna be sure that you placed the proxy snippet in the correct place.  
Also it would be nice to see a picture from your developer console of how it proceeds the request.

Comment: i have added the package.json

Comment: Yeah but I dont see here the proxy snippet? I have edited my post,  copy this as your new package.json and restart your react app, let me know how it went.

Comment: As funny as it might sound - you never know how someone did something so its better to make sure, can you post a screenshot from developer tools? I would like to how your get requests is looking in there

Comment: Ok could you please wait a bit

Comment: Do you mean Chrome dev tools

Comment: Yeah, like when you inspect your GET request in chrome dev tools and sure - I got time!

Comment: Nothing is coming up I Chrome dev tools

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213919/discussion-between-code-yard-and-damian-busz).

Comment: I will hit you up after my break at work, so 30 mins